# How can I sort an array of dates so it is non-contiguous?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, contiguous

If I start with a contiguous sequence of dates:

```
(Date.today..(Date.today + 30)).to_a
```

How can I sort this array so that all dates, in sequence, are at least 1 day apart?

I realise that this would of course not be possible for an array of 2 contiguous dates.

Comment: This is called a [partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). There will be *several* linear extensions that are valid, so something like a comparison sort (which requires a *total* order) will not be applicable. Have you looked into [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
dates = (Date.today..(Date.today + 30)).to_a
dates.each_with_index{|d,i| dates.push(dates.delete(d)) if i % 2}
```

Comment: I believe this is the same as the answer I was going to suggest, in plain English: remove all dates with an even index and place them at the end.  So, for example, {1,2,3,4,5,6} becomes {1,3,5,2,4,6}.

Answer (score 2):

Has the array always an even length? is so, I'd simply write (easily modifiable for odd length if required):

```
>> (1..6).each_slice(2).to_a.transpose.flatten(1)
=> [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(1..6).partition(&:odd?).flatten #=>[1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]
```

works with ranges (or any enumerable) regardless of even or odd elements.

Comment: This really doesn't work at all for the OP's request of an array of Dates.

Comment: Sure it does `dates.partition { |date| date.day.odd? }.flatten`

Comment: No, it does not.  Say the 6 days span the end of one month and the beginning of the next so that their days look like this: [30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4].  Applying your suggestion to this would still leave 31 and 1 next to each other.

Answer (score -1):

The foolish solution:

```
dates = (Date.today..(Date.today + 30)).to_a
begin
  ary   = dates.shuffle
  valid = (ary.select.each_with_index { |element, i| 
    ( i == ary.length-1 || (ary[i+1]  - element).abs  > 1 ) &&
    ( i == 0            || (element   - ary[i-1]).abs > 1 )
  })
end until valid.length == dates.length
ary
```

Only use if you couldn't care less about performance ;-)